# Creating several Android radio streaming Apps with Eclipse but can install only 1

Tags: android, eclipse, internet-radio

I am starting doing my first steps in the Android Apps development and I hope to get some guidance from some experts.

I have installed Eclipse successfully and created an App that is merely streaming one shoutcast radio station.

The big issues started in the moment I wanted to create the second Radio App to play a second different radio station. 
The second App is somehow identical to the first, with only change being that it points to a different shoutcast http link...and it has also some different icons/logo.

I had many problems understanding how to duplicate the Radio App with Eclipse and be allowed to save it. Anyway now I believe this is solved but the copy and paste job is probably what has originated a second problem.

== The issue:  Now, after having completed the Second "Radio App", my Sony smartphone asks me if I want to UPDATE the First Radio App I successfully installed, rather than letting me install the second.

So, obviously even if I changed the name of the App in many lines, there must be something that makes my phone see the second App as a duplicate and a potential update to the first radio app. 
In fact it is a second and different App and I need to install both of them and even a third App for a third radio station!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your app `manifest` tag, there is a `package` attribute. This value is your app's unique identifier. If it is the same, it is treated as the same app.

See: [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

Comment: Thank you tachyonflux. Are you referring to the line 3 in AndroidManifest.xml:  3 package="com.tt.radio2"  ?  If yes I tried to change the name quickly adding the number 2 at the end of it, but then it gives "compilation errors" in several "src" items. Would you please tell me how to change the package name without leaving orphan or unlinked items behind? Then I will be able to try it. THANK YOU for helping me out.

Comment: The other tags in your manifest, like activity will refer to your .java files. So the easiest way is to change your java package to match the change.

Comment: I am afraid that for some reasons it's not working for me... So still if I make the apk and everything ready for one radio station, I won't be able to create the second .apk as it sees still the first as the same and the phone asks if I want to "update" it. So bad.... And  now Android Studio interacting and telling me that I shouldn't import/export with Eclipse... not sure why, perhaps to confuse me more :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse (latest current version), right click on the project from "Package Explorer" (left side of the panel), from the opening menu' select "Android Tools" and select "Rename Application Package". You will be asked for the new package name. You can't change the "structure" of it.

Eclipse will warn/inform you about the change that is going to apply.

Eclipse will change the name of the package everywhere is needed, accordingly. Doing the same manually, most likely you will face ugly results and spend more time.